# Клик по объекту, поверх которого есть другие объекты

Tags: html, css, javascript

На странице есть ссылка, при некоторых обстоятельствах поверх неё может находиться полупрозрачный div-контейнер. Как проще всего можно сделать так, чтобы ссылка продолжала работать при клике, будучи визуально прикрытой другим блоком?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Запихать точно над ссылкой совсем_прозрачный_див, размером точно со ссылку и Z-index 1000; Ловить клик по нему.
2. Пытаться ловить координаты клика (для извращенцев).